# ALT followed by Q (custome shortcut) is not working with browser in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, alt

I am trying to implement a keyboard shortcut for my application. I want to use ALT + Q combination. However, when I try to run the code and press ALT key, it sets focus on the browsers menu bar control and it fails.

I tried to stop event propagation by several methods like,

```
function KeyDownEventHandler() {
    if (event.keyCode == 18) {
       //stop code 
    }
}

stopPropagation(event);
CancleBubbling();
return false;
event.preventDefault();
```

Still it behaves the way. 
EDIT - **Actually the problem is not with detection. When user press ALT key and release it and Q key is pressed after that, it highlights browser menu. It doesn't call function for custom shortcut.**

Is it the default behaviour of the browser ? Can we override it ?

Please help in the same. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rw4km/14/) detecting exactly "ALT+Q" sequence:

```
document.onkeydown = KeyCheck;
var previousKeyCode = 0;
function KeyCheck(e) {
    var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    switch (KeyID)
    {
        case 18:
            previousKeyCode = 18;
            break;
        case 81:
            if (previousKeyCode == 18) {
                alert("ALT+Q Pressed!!!")
            }
            previousKeyCode=KeyID;
            break;
       default: previousKeyCode=KeyID;
    }
}
```

Comment: In IE10 it flashs the menu bar then closes it when the alert comes up

Comment: i didn't quite understand what is wrong with ie10. On my pc IE10 ff and chrome work the same

Comment: Oh probably something on my pc

Comment: Actually the problem is not with detection. When user press ALT key and release it and Q key is pressed after that, it highlights browser menu. It doesn't call function for custom shortcut.

Comment: You said in your question that you want to detect ALT+Q combination..... didn't you?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Not exactly. I have edited the question. Sorry for the false alarm.